# ERROR: File not found

Tags: graphics, errors, pdftex, includegraphics, png

So this question has been asked a lot of times and I´ve tried every suggestion on this subject. none of which has worked for me.
[image: Error screen]

Here I just tried printing an image in my pdf. I've tried the following

- Makings sure there are no typos in the file
- using: tools > PDFLaTeX
- doing changes to the root folder in MikTeX settings

It seems that the tex file does find my png. If I change the name of the image file such that it is incorrect, then the console gives me an error: "file xxx not found". But if the file name is correct, I get the 'file not found' window.

Thanks!

Comment: you have spurious  doubled `{{..}}` in `\includegraphics` the exact behaviour of that depends which version of graphics you have installed, but it is always wrong.

Comment: it would also help if you showed the complete error from the log file not just a screenshot of your editor dialog.

Comment: For testing purposes, I suggest that you don't use accented characters in the `\graphicspath`, and that you rename the picture to something consisting only of letters. If this works, you can add, step by step, underscores, parentheses and accented letters.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback guys but I've figured it out, see answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. Just as others had problems with typos and things like that my problem also had ~nothing with the code to do really. The problem was in the image format. Yes, it was .png but as I tried opening it in paint.net I also got an error. So I took a snip of my image and re-saved it. (an alternative is using an online image converter)